# How to do drop gap between two details band?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a main report, it has two detail band in each one it has subreport, firts it contains a fiel that could has one or many result, it show result result verticaly, ok, the next detail band contains a subreport that only contain text field with a long string. My problem is that, between they or in the end of firts show a gap in blank. How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

The height of detail band & their sub-report should be same & you have to fix following properties:

For Sub-reports:

```
Position Type = FLOAT
Stretch  Type = NO STRETCH
```

For `Text fields` in sub-reports

```
Position Type = Fix relative to Top
Stretch  Type = Relative to Band Height
```

Comment: Hi @monika thank you by your answer, but my root problem was other, thank any way

Answer (score 0):

anyone answer my question until now, or better say it, I havent the solution to my problem until now, jejejeje well, Now, I have de answer to my question, The gap that was generate  was in my first detail band, inside of my subreport, did find this solution by the next step.

1.- I did wrap with frame all sub report to find what had the blank space.

2.- Inside of the subreport contains other subreports one of them has a result set from query db, if it is set with the heigth of the row of field on it. it duplicate the heigth size of the return row, that was my problem.

3.- Only I stretch my subreport and without problem.

I hope that you can find the solution with it, ifis the case.

gretting.